# How to convert time of the date and count the days in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset about users taking online courses. It has features like, 'id', 'event', 'time'. I groupby them and want to know the frequency of a user doing every event on specific days. I want to count them in days.

```
lt = log_train.groupby(['enrollment_id','event','time']).size()
print(lt)


enrollment_id  event       time
1              access  2014-06-14T09:38:39    2
                       2014-06-14T09:38:48    1
                       2014-06-19T06:21:16    2
                       2014-06-19T06:21:32    1
                       2014-06-19T06:21:45    1
                                           ..
200887     navigate    2014-07-24T03:27:16    1
200887     navigate    2014-07-24T03:27:16    1
           page_close  2014-07-24T04:19:55    1
           video       2014-07-24T04:19:57    1
200888     access      2014-07-24T03:48:14    2
           discussion  2014-07-24T03:47:57    1
           navigate    2014-07-24T03:47:17    1
                       2014-07-24T03:47:28    1
                       2014-07-24T03:48:01    1
```

From the information I have seen in another dataset there are userIDs, courseIDs and course range time.

```
usercourse = pd.merge(enroll,date,how="left", on= 'course_id' )



 enrollment_id                          username  \

0                   1  9Uee7oEuuMmgPx2IzPfFkWgkHZyPbWr0   
1                   3  1qXC7Fjbwp66GPQc6pHLfEuO8WKozxG4   
2                   4  FIHlppZyoq8muPbdVxS44gfvceX9zvU7 

                           course_id        from          to  
0       DPnLzkJJqOOPRJfBxIHbQEERiYHu5ila  2014-06-12  2014-07-11  
1       7GRhBDsirIGkRZBtSMEzNTyDr2JQm4xx  2014-06-19  2014-07-18  
2       DPnLzkJJqOOPRJfBxIHbQEERiYHu5ila  2014-06-12  2014-07-11
```

Every single user has only 1 course and all the courses have the same range with 30 days. So what I want to have should be similar like this,

```
enrollment_id  event      #ofDays   #ofActionTimes
1              access      2         2
                           10        6
                           30        2
                                   ..
200887         navigate    23        1
               page_close  30        1
               video       1         1
200888         access      12        2
               discussion  2         1
               navigate    5         3
                           29        4  

**#ofDays means at the Nth day of a course.
#ofActionTimes means how often an event happens on the Nth day.**
```

Since every course started from different dates I have no idea how to generate this data form on python.
Hope someone could help me to solve the problem!

Comment: What is `time` and `frequency`?  Can you provide `usercourse` data that can be used to construct your example output?

Comment: hi @andrew_reece, I updated the explanation at the bottom of last code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `merge`, `groupby`, and `count` to get what you want.

First, some example data.  This is based on the data you provided, but I've modified it so that the output can be clearly traced from the starting data.

```
data1 = {"enrollment_id":[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
         "event":["access","access","access","navigate","access",
                  "page_close","navigate","navigate","video"],
         "time":["2014-06-14T09:38:39", "2014-06-14T09:38:48",
                 "2014-06-19T06:21:16", "2014-06-19T06:21:32", 
                 "2014-06-21T06:21:45", "2014-06-22T06:21:16",
                 "2014-06-19T06:21:32", "2014-06-20T06:21:16",
                 "2014-06-20T06:21:16"]}

data2 = {"enrollment_id":[1,2,3],
         "username":["user1", "user2", "user3"],
         "course_id":["course1", "course2", "course3"],
         "course_from":["2014-06-12", "2014-06-19", "2014-06-12"],
         "course_to":["2014-07-11", "2014-07-18", "2014-07-11"]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1
   enrollment_id       event                 time
0              1      access  2014-06-14T09:38:39
1              1      access  2014-06-14T09:38:48
2              1      access  2014-06-19T06:21:16
3              1    navigate  2014-06-19T06:21:32
4              2      access  2014-06-21T06:21:45
5              2  page_close  2014-06-22T06:21:16
6              3    navigate  2014-06-19T06:21:32
7              3    navigate  2014-06-20T06:21:16
8              3       video  2014-06-20T06:21:16

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2
  course_id  enrollment_id course_from   course_to username
0   course1              1  2014-06-12  2014-07-11    user1
1   course2              2  2014-06-19  2014-07-18    user2
2   course3              3  2014-06-12  2014-07-11    user3
```

We want to know how many times a specific `event` happened for a specific `enrollment_id`, with a separate count for each day of the course.

Derive the course day number `course_day_num` by subtracting `course_from` (the course start date) from `event_date`.

```
df = (df1.merge(df2[["enrollment_id", "course_from"]], 
           on="enrollment_id", how="left")
)
df["event_date"] = pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime(df1.time).dt.date)
df["course_from"] = pd.to_datetime(df["course_from"])
df["course_day_num"] = (df.event_date - df["course_from"]).dt.days
```

Then `groupby` each `course_day_num` to get the event count, per person, per course day:

```
groupby_cols = ["enrollment_id", "event", "event_date", "course_day_num"]

df.groupby(groupby_cols).event_date.count()

enrollment_id  event       event_date  course_day_num
1              access      2014-06-14  2                 2
                           2014-06-19  7                 1
               navigate    2014-06-19  7                 1
2              access      2014-06-21  2                 1
               page_close  2014-06-22  3                 1
3              navigate    2014-06-19  7                 1
                           2014-06-20  8                 1
               video       2014-06-20  8                 1
Name: event_date, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Again @andrew_reece, I was wondering if you could take a look at my new question posted here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988238/how-to-fill-0-and-nan-for-a-dataframe-after-groupby-it-in-python. It seems no one can give me a hand:(