# How to fill 0 and NaN for a dataframe after groupby it in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-processing

I have a dataframe looks like this after I groupby them.

```
gb = new_user_log.groupby(['msno', 'date', 'num_25', 'num_50',
                          'num_75', 'num_985', 'num_100',
                          'num_unq', 'total_secs', 'days']).days.count()
```

Part of the dataframe shows here:

```
  msno                                          date        num_25  num_50  num_75  num_985  num_100  num_unq  total_secs  days
    ++orpnUqSevh2M5A97pRRiONA58g5m9DwaNrhD44HY0=  2016-08-14  78      13      3       3        77       84       18987.862   2       1
    +0krxpTkQT7hciN95OEp7i2lyKvbXft887VNQGF6xN4=  2016-12-22  27      23      5       2        11       65       5946.577    35      1
                                                                                                                             98      1
    +1eAmfPiXsMG0J+U/j7YTeXO+u0/ZhZqmoXfXKOY57I=  2016-12-17  8       2       2       2        126      131      32629.128   46      1
    +1zyLKrstPYDOnoyooqqb0+VmmovONd9N3QZynT7rq0=  2016-07-14  18      2       1       3        46       66       10253.571   196     1
                                                  2016-09-17  11      3       1       6        81       45       12970.416   261     1
                                                  2016-11-17  5       1       3       2        8        19       2614.571    322     1
    +28j7X4BShC9g2C4No4xAmzXuhLlmMbFDYWZcbblCEs=  2015-11-21  1       2       1       2        88       94       23580.548   45      1
                                                  2016-03-28  12      6       5       4        36       61       11596.887   173     1
    +2GtgQNpMuIG0Vy1ycAbfla0zRni6NKtRLlyyuHHB8I=  2015-07-18  15      1       2       2        73       75       19179.451   102     1
                                                  2016-07-29  7       2       1       1        8        17       2515.486    479     1
                                                  2016-11-09  45      6       3       1        71       93       19865.317   582     1
```

So the first little problem I hope to solve is give each of 'msno'(userID) a number, not as a string type...

All these features `num_25  num_50  num_75  num_985  num_100  num_unq`  `total_secs` are counting events happened in each day.

The last feature `days` is calculated by `days = date - transaction_date` means the number of days a user own the product. And the first`transaction_date` for each user means the first time to buy this product. It comes from the dataframe belows,

```
                                                msno  payment_method_id  \
0       QA7uiXy8vIbUSPOkCf9RwQ3FsT8jVq2OxDr8zqa7bRQ=                 39   
20      GBy8qSz16X5iYWD+3CMxv/Hm6OPSrXBYtmbnlRtknW0=                 33   
44      T0FF6lumjKcqEO0O+tUH2ytc+Kb9EkeaLzcVUiTr1aE=                 40   
72      9iW/UpqRoviya9CQh64RoYLPjiws8+biwscN+g5qYm4=                 37   
86      LUCi7i5FeNuZz4DB0zKu8J80rgr2uCO8YHCSW9PZfAk=                 38   
98      qCagaTL3UbMn0zvdMDDUoonbei70q1eASKrXa1cZGCs=                 38   
120     nsx5IGkCueevv0vFHB4jkG0HdRl6m6ltB8U9Guo5nS0=                 40   
123     nsx5IGkCueevv0vFHB4jkG0HdRl6m6ltB8U9Guo5nS0=                 40   


      transaction_date membership_expire_date  
0            2016-10-31             2016-12-21    
20           2016-03-31             2016-04-30  
44           2015-03-28             2015-04-27  
72           2015-05-04             2015-06-03   
86           2016-03-13             2016-08-24  
98           2015-03-20             2015-04-19   
120          2016-04-07             2016-05-06   
123          2017-01-01             2017-02-06
```

You can see that in `days` there are only a few values for each user. So is it possible to fill all other days of the event with 0 to expand the dataframe to a very sparse one? The rule I have to follow is to find the maximum value in `days` column (In this sample is `582`) then fill all 582 days with 0s for every user under those events columns when no events happened.

From the title I said fill NaN because some of the users have multiple `transcation_date` and `membership_expire_date` records(See the last two rows). For example, I want to compute the difference between the second `transcation_date` - the first `membership_expire_date`(similar to how `days` come) of the user then fill in NaN in this range time and also maybe `the third starts - the second ends`(It can be a lot of range time for some users even about 30). So two types of values should be filled, 0 and NaN.

I don't know if I made these questions clearly and indeed that was a lot.. If anyone could help me out or even give me some hints, you must be my lifesaver!

Comment: Your question needs to be clearer in order for people to help. There are at least 3 problems: (1) You have at least 3 questions, but you have not clearly delineated them. (2) It's not clear how your example data reflect your question. (3) Your second and third questions are hard to understand. IIUC, Question 1 is: How to map unique strings (`msno`) to numeric values? Question 2: How to transition from wide-to-long (melt/unpivot) for some parts of your data frame? Question 3:  How to do (some other kind of computation) with `transaction_date` and `membership_expire_date`?
 Please explain more.

Comment: For what I'm calling Question 2, it's not clear from your example data exactly what are the rows per user that need to be filled with `0`.  It's also not clear how you use the second data frame to derive `days` in the first.  If you can provide example data that *clearly* show how you start with a small representative example, compute `days`, and decide which rows need to be given `0` values, that's a good start.  Your last question about `NaN` is completely undecipherable - you may want to open a separate question for that, or, if it is connected, explain it with very simple code examples.